# How to shake an image on hover and on time

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to shake an image when user is above the image (hover effect) and every 5 seconds. My code:

```css
.opona:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

/*
.opona {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.82s;
}
*/

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="opona">
  <img src="https://www.firestonetire.com/content/dam/bridgestone/consumer/fst/tire-images/Firehawk%20AS/FST_Firehawk_AS.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/original" alt="" width="50px">
</div>
```

When I remove the comment from .opona the effect doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: hi, i suggest you take a look at this article https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/

Comment: I don't see hover effect in Your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want the `animation` to last `10.82s`, where the *"moving"* part only takes *0.82s* therefore leaving *10s* gap before repetition. In order to do that all you have to do is some tweaking with the defined `@keyframes` `%`s.

*0.82/10.82 = ~7.6%*, i.e. the *"moving"* part only takes around *7.6%* of the *animation-duration*.

So to update the `%`s just multiply the current *values* by 0.076:

```css
.opona:hover {
  animation: shake 10.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  .76%, 6.84% {transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0)}
  1.52%, 6.08% {transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0)}
  2.28%, 3.8%, 5.32% {transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0)}
  3.04%, 4.56% {transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0)}
}
```

```html
<div class="opona">
  <img src="https://www.firestonetire.com/content/dam/bridgestone/consumer/fst/tire-images/Firehawk%20AS/FST_Firehawk_AS.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/original" alt="" width="50px">
</div>
```

Comment: How to run this animation on every 10s ?

Comment: @AdamKowalski Modified.